# Parsing through complex json in C#

Tags: c#

I am attempting to parse through the following to determine the Name and Goals of the top scoring Player for the specific "AC Milan" in this json file that contains many other teams and countries. The main issue I have been running into when I parse it as a JObject is the inability to parse a JObject as a JArray as this json file is pretty messy.

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.
```

[image]

Comment: I guess, it's an array. So, I agree with the parser that it can't parse array as object.

Comment: "Represents a JSON array." - https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm

Comment: Can you post  part of json as a text pls if you want some help to find the score?

Comment: Post code as text and not as image. And also please post the code where you are parsing that json. You are trying to create a `JObject` but your json is a `JArray`. That's what the error is telling you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a json array, so you have to use for parsing JArray, not JObject

```
var jsonParsed=JArray.Parse(json);
```

and IMHO you posted an invalid json, it needs "{" before "AC Milan". So it should be like this

```
[
  {
    "Italy": [
      {
        "SerieA": [
          {
            "ACMilan": [
              {
                "Name": "Player1",
                "Goals": 3
              },
              {
                "Name": "Player2",
                "Goals": 5
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

in this case you can use this query

```
List<Score>  milanPlayersList = JArray.Parse(json)
.Select(i=> ((JObject) i).Properties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name=="Italy" ).Value).First()
.Select(i=> ((JObject) i).Properties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name=="SerieA" ).Value).First()
.Select(i=> ((JObject) i).Properties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name=="ACMilan" ).Value).First()
.Select(i=>  i.ToObject<Score>()).ToList().Dump();
```

using this list you can make any kind of queries.

result

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Player1",
    "Goals": 3
  },
  {
    "Name": "Player2",
    "Goals": 5
  }
]
```

class

```
public class Score
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Goals {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: The following still errors out. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. It's a bit confusing.

var objects = JArray.Parse(json); // parse as array  
var playerArray = objects["Italy"]["Serie A"]["AC Milan"]

Comment: Just post your json as it is. It seems it is not valid one . Where did you get it?

Comment: You have to distinguish if something is an `object` or an `array`. If `objects` is a `JArray`, you have to access elements by index like in any other array. So it would be `objects[0]["Italy"]["Serie A"][0]["AC Milan"]`

Comment: The json was a dummy of how I intend to design my json file when I extract this data. But now I realize that is flawed too. I will design it better and be sure to ask a better question next time. Thank you Serge and @derpirscher. I appreciate the time and honesty.

Comment: @noob_23 I updated my answer. You can use it in the future.